# Why are Wemf and Google Analytics telling me so different things?

Tags: statistics, count, google-analytics

The website works with Wemf and Google Analytics, but they are giving me very different results; WEMF counts 10 - 30 % more page views than Google Analytics... Why can this be?

Google Analytics works only with JavaScript enabled, yes - but I don't think that's the reason for this difference. The site which should be counted is a famous newspaper in Switzerland.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know much about WEMF. Could it be that Google Analytics does a better job at detecting and not counting search engine spider traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!! I googled a little bit for "Google Analytics search engine spider" and it really seems as Google Analytics doesn't count those...

Thank you very much for that info, helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in addition to the spider traffic, one or the other services might actually lose track based on in page javascript too.  There are a hundred different possibilities of why the numbers are off.  I've never seen analytics packages match up 100%, usually if they're within 5% of each other you're doing good.

...and btw, I've worked for a few of the big analytics companies, this is a known situation.  I say situation because it is also accepted that no one has 100% right on numbers - too many variables to compensate for that level of sigma.